# How to assign an integer for every element in the list

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

```
classes = list(set(os.listdir(current_dir + '/Logos/')))
print(classes)

['twitch.png', 'logitech.png', 'nba2k2.png', 'microsoft2.png', 'ubisoft2.png', 'corsair.png', 'xbox.png', 'messenger.png', 'nvidia3.png', 'logo4.png', 'uta3.png', 'complexity2.png', '100thieves3.png', 'google2.png', 'logo1.png', 'warner1.png', 'caffeine3.png', 'tencen2.png', 'logo2.png', 'team-solo.png', 'sony.png', 'wizards2.png', 'nba2k1.png', 'tencent1.png', 'uta1.png', 'loaded1.png', 'toysrus.png', 'seeklogo.png', 'caffeine1.png', 'tog2.png', 'complexity1.png', 'blizzard2.png', 'clg1.png', 'streamhathcet.png', 'nvidia2.png', 'complexity4.png', 'playstation.png', 'loaded2.png', 'amazon2.png', '100thieves1.png', 'ader1.png', 'xbox2.png', 'warner2.png', 'logo6.png', 'logitech2.png', 'wizards1.png', 'nvidia.png', 'intel.png', 'microsoft.png', 'google.png', 'esl1.png', '100thieves2.png', '100thieves5.png', 'ubisoft1.png', 'esl3.png', 'ubuntu2.png', 'twitch2.png', 'amazon3.png', 'logo5.png', 'ader2.png', 'tencent3.png', 'stream-hatchet.png', 'complexity3.png', 'nba2k3.png', 'uta2.png', '100thieves4.png', 'amazon.png', 'corsair2.png', 'clg2.png', 'nbc-peacock.png', 'team-solo2.png', 'ubuntu.png', 'msn.png', 'blizzard1.png', 'ader3.png', 'riot-games.png', 'esl2.png', 'logo3.png', 'ps5.png']
```

I want to assign an int from 1 to n. The purpose is that, if the code sees an element from this list, it appends to a text file its assigned value.

I don't want to do this with if statements.

Comment: Use list indexing. `classes[1] == 'logitech.png'`

Comment: `classes.index('logitech.png')` returns `1`.

Comment: Looking at the answers so far it seems that your question is unclear. Add some more detail to your question including an example of where your code would "see" an element, and what should be output to the file when one is seen. Probably a dictionary would be the best solution if you have many filenames, or just list indexing as already suggested by @Barmar. It is difficult to answer without details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dict using comprehension.

```
my_dict = {i: classes[i] for i in range(len(classes))}
```

Example result:

```
{1: "twitch.png",
 2: "logitech.png",
...
}
```

(it's not so different by a standard list though)

Comment: Can you do this the other way around? Like, I want to get `1` if I do `my_dict["twitch.png"]`.  1 could be a string, np.

Comment: my_dict.keys()[mydict.values().index("twitch.png")] Consider also just using a list

Comment: my_dict.keys()[my_dict.values().index("twitch.png")]

Comment: `AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'index'`

Answer (score 0):

if you want a list you can do something like this,

```
classes = ["hello", "world", "hellow", "world"]
rv = [f"{x}_{i + 1}" for (i, x) in enumerate(classes)]
```

```
result => ['hello_1', 'world_2', 'hellow_3', 'world_4']
```

You also have a but more freedom in how you want to structure the name inside the f""